# iOS in app purchase, how to determine if app store user account has changed

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, account

I'm building an app that requires in app purchase. Everything works ok, but i have a problem.

I have a list of products that can be purchased. When purchasing a product, i keep the product's identifier in the user defaults, so i can provide content even though there is no internet connection.

Problem:
User1 buys some products. User1 logs out from appStore (in Settings).
User 2 logs in appStore. Open app. 
Now user 2 will be able to see the content user1 unlocked.

How do i prevent this?

Thanks